# How come my ANTLR Grammar is failing to match?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

My grammar is below:

```
grammar BirdGrammar;


lines: (init '\n')*;
init  : lineCode
      | continuation;

sep : ' '
    | '-'
    ;


lineCode  : interfaceList
          | protocolList
          | interfaceAddress
          | interfaceFlags
          ;

interfaceList     : '1001' sep INTERFACENAME ' ' interfaceStatus ' (index=' index ')';
protocolList      : '1002';
interfaceAddress  : '1003';
interfaceFlags    : '1004';
continuation      : ' ';

interfaceStatus   : 'up'
                  | 'DOWN';

index         : INDEX;
INTERFACENAME : [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
INDEX         : [0-9]+;
```

I'm trying to feed it the following input data (through grun):

```
1001-eth0 up (index=110)
1001-ip6gre0 DOWN (index=113)
```

When I do, I get the following errors:

```
line 1:20 mismatched input '110' expecting INDEX
line 2:25 mismatched input '113' expecting INDEX
```

Now, it looks like to me that INDEX (the rule) should match 110, and 113 as it's looking for repeating [0-9]+. Does anyone spot any obvious problems with my grammar, or input?

Answer (score 0):

Your lexer rule `INTERFACENAME` matches the input `110`. Since that rule is located before `INDEX` in the grammar, it will always take precedence. In fact, this grammar will *never* produce an `INDEX` token in its current form because the `INTERFACENAME` will always match the index.

Also note that due to the inclusion of the literal `'1001'` in a parser rule, the input `1001` will always be its own unique token which is never a `INTERFACENAME` or `INDEX`. The same applies to `1002`, `1003`, and `1004`.

Comment: So, how do I work around this? Is there a fundamental "bug" in my grammar, and how I've approached it?

Answer (score 0):

Can INTERFACENAME start with a numberic character? If not, try something like:
INTERFACENAME : ([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9])*;